# Map each item of a stream to a promise and return its value

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I am trying to map each item of a stream to a promise, something like this

```
myStream$
  .flatMap(id => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(database.get(id)))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

`myStream$` has about 15 items. Since none of these items can be found in the database, each promise will be rejected. I was expecting 15 log outputs printing an error. However all I get is one single error

> rx.js:77 Uncaught {"status":404,"name":"not_found","message":"missing","reason":"missing"}

Why am I only getting one error instead of 15?

Comment: Does this link help:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md#example

Basically they define the promise and then subscribe to return values

Comment: Mmm, not really, sorry. The basically do the same thing as me. The problem here rather is that I only get a single output here instead of multiples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected - whenever an error is thrown, the stream will finalize (in other words: "stop & unsubscribe all subscribers").

If you want your stream to complete properly regardless of one or all db-request failing, you have to handle the error inside the sub-stream that wraps the promise, since a `reject` will be evaluated as an `error` in RxJS.

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .flatMap(
    id => mockRequest(id)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return Rx.Observable.empty();  // here we just return an empty stream, so the "main"-stream won't receive the error and continue with the other ids in the queue
      })
  )
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log(val),
    error => console.error("Stream hit an error and will finalize", error),
    complete => console.log("Done!")
  );
  
function mockRequest(id) {
  return Rx.Observable.throw("Request failed for: " + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note: Instead of `return Rx.Observable.empty();` you can of course return any fallback-value via `Observable.of("myFallbackValue")`

---

Sidenote & suggestion: You'll have it easier when you make your rest-calls directly with RxJS and not have to wrap a promise. (though technically both are perfectly valid ways)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! As for the REST calls, it is a database call to PouchDB within an Electron app. I'm not sure they provide an API other than their own promise- and callback-based methods.

Comment: Ok a quick google search shows various results regarding pouchdb and rxjs